# jade whitespace removal

Tags: javascript, html, pug

**Jade**

```
 .foo
 .foo
```

**Result**

```
 <div class="foo"></div>
 <div class="foo"></div>
```

**Desired result**

```
 <div class="foo"></div><div class="foo"></div>
```

in haml I would do something like `.foo><` but that does not work in jade. I have searched and come up empty handed on how to handle this. How do I achieve the desired result? I am using codekit for jade. Thanks folks!

Comment: did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: What's the difference? HTML isn't whitespace aware...

Comment: @elclanrs html certainly is whitespace aware. Consider if `.foo` is an `inline-block` for example.

Comment: I see what you mean... What I meant is no matter how many spaces you put HTML will count it just as one, so 100 spaces would be just one space.

Comment: @elclanrs that is certainly true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set option `pretty` to `false`, depends on how you apply jade to your source file. Should be `false` by default?

Comment: never used codekit, but there must be a preferences page or something like that for Jade. From the website: "...Process Less, Sass, Stylus, Jade, Haml, Slim, CoffeeScript, Javascript and Compass files automatically each time you save. Easily set options for each language..."

Comment: It doesn't have that option, but it sounds like you have the right answer. I'll leave the question open to see if there is another way, otherwise I will accept you answer. Thank you.

Comment: just had a look at a [video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/111-get-yourself-preprocessing-in-just-a-few-minutes/), maybe you turn off this `Regular (indented)` mode..

Comment: that did it, but made the output very ugly, oh well.